# Distortion while saving matlab figure as a eps file

Tags: matlab, pdf, figure, eps, distortion

```
saveas(gcf,'result.pdf');
```

After I using above command to output my figure into a eps file, I got the following result.

[image: figure.eps]

However, the actual figure is like the following.

[image: figure.jpg]

I have tried using other commands like

```
saveas(gcf, 'result.eps');
print -depsc myplot.eps
```

or even the 'export_fig' library,but still can't get correct figure output.

Does anyone know where is the key point of this problem? Thanks.

---

**[ Update ]**

Following dpwe's comment, after zooming in the figure, the result of .eps is like this
[image: large.eps]

and the original figure is like this
[image: large.jpg]

Yes, it seems that they are much more similar!

Comment: It seems like the problem may come from rasterizing the 2048 rows.  Can you zoom in on, say, the top 200 rows so we can see exactly how each pixel behaves?  Screen display often simply subsamples, but eps output may attempt to average.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, and I have updated the figure as you mentioned. And, as I can realize, the different sampling methods between screen display and eps output may just be the reason of this phenomenon right?

Comment: Looks like it. You have to be careful plotting images where each element occupies less than one physical pixel.  This is actually a problem of aliasing - for better fidelity, you need to low-pass filter your image before subjecting it to the (inevitable) down sampling of the final display. It looks as if the original eps output is doing this at some level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The saveas function uses a default size for saving figures, I think it's something like 3/4 of your screen resolution. You can figure it out by looking at the number of pixels in the image (for a png anyway). If you run

```
set(gcf,'Position',[a b c d]);
saveas(gcf, 'result.eps');
```

to resize the figure to the size that saveas will use to save it before it saves it, that might help.

Comment: Yes, after resizing the figure, the difference between matlab figure and eps output is much smaller. And I think that is just what @dpwe said above. Thanks!